# Rust: Itertools::GroupBy and ownership

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, itertools-groupby

I am a newbie in Rust, and I am having trouble understanding `Itertools::GroupBy`.

Here is an example I came up with to practice `GroupBy`. Given an array of integers:

- Group it based on the value of the numbers.
- Keep only groups with more than 3 elements.
- Return  a vector with the keys of the survived groups.

As an example, given this array

```
[1,1,1,1,-2,-2,-3,-3,-3,-3,4,4]
```

I want to return the vector `(1,-3)`, because 1 and 3 appears more than three times in the array.

Here is my attempt

```
let groups = [1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, 4, 4]
  .into_iter()
  .group_by(|element| *element)
  .into_iter()
  .filter(|(_, value)| value.count() > 3)
  .map(|(key, _)| key)
  .collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

You can try this out in the [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=04b0e6b02f6217249d3863b778937f1c).

The line with the filter results in the error: "cannot move out of `*value` which is behind a shared reference", where `*value` is moved due to the method call `count()`.

After experimenting, I notice that I can fix the code adding a `map`

```
let groups = [1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, 4, 4]
    .into_iter()
    .group_by(|element| *element)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(key, value)| (key, value.collect::<Vec<i32>>()))
    .filter(|(_, value)| value.len() > 3)
    .map(|(key, _)| key)
    .collect::<Vec<i32>>();
```

However, I would like to understand why my original attempt is not working. I understand that it has to do with borrowing, but my knowledge is still too basic.

Comment: You say *"Group it based on the sign of the numbers"* and then you group by number, not sign of number. Which one is it?

Comment: You are right, I edited the text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.filter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter) doesn't give you ownership of the item, it doesn't even give you mutability, it just gives you immutable references. It expects you to deduce from the *immutable* input whether something should be kept or removed.
The items are just bypassed, `.filter()` is expected not to modify them, just to select them.

To understand how many values are in your group, though, you have to iterate through it, because the `value` variable is an iterator. You cannot iterate through it, however, because for obvious reasons that would modify the `value` variable, which isn't allowed inside of `.filter()`.

There is a solution, though: The [`.filter_map()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) method combines `.filter()` and `.map()` in a single operation and gives you the element owned and to do with as you please:

```
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let groups = [1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2, -3, -3, -3, -3, 4, 4]
        .into_iter()
        .group_by(|element| *element)
        .into_iter()
        .filter_map(|(key, value)| (value.count() > 3).then_some(key))
        .collect::<Vec<i32>>();

    println!("{:?}", groups);
}
```

```
[1, -3]
```

Comment: Just to add some justification for these choices: `filter`'s predicate function *can't* take ownership of its argument, as it has to leave it intact (unmoved) so that it can continue to exist in the post-`filter` iterator. `filter_map`'s function *has* to take ownership of its argument, otherwise the owned `T` in the returned `Option<T>` would need to be produced from a reference that exists only for the length of the function call, which is not possible in general without cloning.

Comment: @BallpointBen yah, but there is nothing intrinsic that would prevent `filter` from taking a mutable reference. But I still think it's a good design choice that it doesn't.